# How to use Docker Image in ECR with AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ecr, amazon-eks

I have created EKS Cluster. I also have docker image in ECR. I am not sure how to use the docker image in pod definition in YAML.

Is it required to give credentials in secret? or EKS IAM role should have permission for ECR?

Any changes in permission have to do for Image in ECR ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you followed the [EKS getting started guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html), everything will work out of the box and you just have to specify the the full image name (e.g. `ACCOUNT.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com/imagename:tag`) in the Pod definition (`spec.containers.image` field).

It works because [Kubernetes has native support for ECR](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#using-aws-ec2-container-registry)
and the [CloudFormation template](https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation/2019-01-09/amazon-eks-nodegroup.yaml) for the Kubernetes worker nodes attaches an `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly` policy to the instance profile.

Comment: This only works if the image is stored in a public ECR repository or am I missing something?

Comment: That works for private ECR in the same account if the `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly` policy is attached to the worker nodes.

Comment: Without creating and maintaining Kubernetes secrets? I have to take another look at it in that case, would make things easier

Comment: No secrets involved.

Comment: @mrucci Just to confirm this is in same account and not cross account ? We today have single ECR across multiple accounts and want this to work for all clusters in different accounts. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Right, by default access is only allowed within the same account.  For cross-account, an ECR repository policy should work: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-policy-examples.html#IAM_allow_other_accounts