# Pull image from ECR to Kubernetes deployment file

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, amazon-ecr

I am facing the issue while pulling the docker image from AWS ECR repository, earlier i used

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=https://index.docker.io/v1/ --docker-username=kammana --docker-password=<your-password> --docker-email=hari.kammana@gmail.com
```

The deployment YAML file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: privateapp
    image: kammana/privateapp:0.0.1
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

but now the secret password is only valid for 12 hours when you generate for ECR, i will have to manually change the secret everytime. This is hectic and i read a Medium [article](https://medium.com/@damitj07/how-to-configure-and-use-aws-ecr-with-kubernetes-rancher2-0-6144c626d42c).

It can creates kind of cron Job but i want to pull the image at runtime by logging in to ECR.

It would be helpful if you could provide some relevant example with respect ECR direct login via Kubernetes and my cluster is not in the same AWS account so AWS IAM Roles is out of question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Docker Image in ECR with AWS EKS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54109603/how-to-use-docker-image-in-ecr-with-aws-eks)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue and I use this in a cron:

```sh
# KUBECTL='kubectl --dry-run=client'
KUBECTL='kubectl'

ENVIRONMENT=sandbox # yes, typo
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=moon-west-1

EXISTS=$($KUBECTL get secret "$ENVIRONMENT-aws-ecr-$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
if [ "$EXISTS" = "$ENVIRONMENT-aws-ecr-$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" ]; then
  echo "Secret exists, deleting"
  $KUBECTL delete secrets "$ENVIRONMENT-aws-ecr-$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"
fi

PASS=$(aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION)
$KUBECTL create secret docker-registry $ENVIRONMENT-aws-ecr-$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION \
    --docker-server=$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com \
    --docker-username=AWS \
    --docker-password=$PASS \
    --docker-email=infra@setu.co --namespace collect
```

Comment: using a dry-run on the create and then piping it to kubectl apply might be  simpler method to sort out the issues if the secret already exists....

Comment: Or delete and re-create it:
kubectl delete secret --ignore-not-found $SECRET_NAME

Answer (score 2):

This is true and the usual way is to get the password everytime you wish to login to ECR.  This is the snippet from AWS documentation which says

> The generated token is valid for 12 hours, which means developers
> running and managing container images have to re-authenticate every 12
> hours manually, or script it to generate a new token, which can be
> somewhat cumbersome in a CI/CD environment. For example if you’re
> using Jenkins to build and push docker images to ECR, you have to set
> up Jenkins instances to re-authenticate using get-login to ECR every
> 12 hours.

[link to the full AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/authenticating-amazon-ecr-repositories-for-docker-cli-with-credential-helper/)

Below is the command to do get the password and login.

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region <<someregion>> | docker login --username <<someusername>> --password-stdin https://<<someaccount>>.amazonaws.com
```

And in your case you will have to write some script within a helper pod to do the below steps.

1. Get the login password and save it in a variable.

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region <<someregion>>
```

2. Delete you existing secret

```
kubectl delete secret <<secretname>>
```

3. Recreate secret with new password.

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=https://index.docker.io/v1/ --docker-username=kammana --docker-password=<newpassword> --docker-email=hari.kammana@gmail.com
```

You could try cronjob to reset this every <12 hours

Comment: Actually i am not good with script, do you anything i can take as reference for cron job or is there any other alternative

Comment: Check [this link](https://medium.com/@damitj07/how-to-configure-and-use-aws-ecr-with-kubernetes-rancher2-0-6144c626d42c)

Comment: And also these 2 articles.  [first](https://tuantranf.me/2020/01/18/how-to-manage-aws-ecr-pull-secret-for-kubernetes/) and [second](https://hub.docker.com/r/frekele/aws-ecr-kubectl)

Comment: I have already referrd this article in the question here, i had a question if i have pull the image separately will it use it when i launch the yaml file.

Comment: The articcle just pulls the image, i have tried with that, but when i launch my YAML files referring to the image getting pulled, it fails

Comment: If you set the imagePullPolicy as IfNotPresent then it won't pull the image again if it exists on the node.

Answer (score 1):

There is this small tool called [`k8s-ecr-login-renew`](https://github.com/nabsul/k8s-ecr-login-renew) that does exactly what you need.

Comment: It is not working i tried doing it, the image is not getting pulled. Do you have anything to reference, i also have a question, i am running this in rancher is it different

Answer (score 0):

We can also use now ECR generator API of External Secrets Operator:
https://external-secrets.io/latest/api/generator/ecr/

This CRD can refresh tokens at regular intervals and update our secrets automatically.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).