# How do I log into ECR to pull images if I can't use docker as a runtime?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubectl

One of the steps to log into ECR required to pull and push images is the following, according to AWS (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/getting-started-cli.html):

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region region | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com
```

However, from starting from Kubernetes v1.24, Docker can no longer be used as a runtime.
In this case, if someone is using:

1. ctr
2. crictl
3. nerdctl

What does the login command become?
I have looked everyone but could not construct it. AWS doesn't have documentation for it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to change anything. Just keep your workflow with `docker login` with AWS ECR as usual.

The reason is Kubernetes still supports Docker-produces images. It only deprecates Docker runtime in favor of runtimes that use the Container Runtime Interface (CRI) created for Kubernetes. For more information, please take a look at [Don't Panic: Kubernetes and Docker](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/02/dont-panic-kubernetes-and-docker/)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve?
If you are looking for a tool to build images inside K8s and push them to ECR, you can use `buildah` and auth to ECR by the command:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION} | buildah login --username AWS --password-stdin ${REPO_URI}
```

If you need provide K8s access to pull images from your ECR it's another case and you can find documentation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54144588/6839933)